# Why is the square root of a sum not equal to the square root of each its addends?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sums-of-squares

Example: Let's presume one was attempting to isolate m below:

A common mistake would be:
$k^2 = m^2 + n^2 \to k = m +n$

Even though: $k^2 = m^2 + n^2 \to k \neq m +n$

If you apply a square root to both sides of the equation, you will have an inequality.

Why is this true?

Comment: There is no inequality. Applying the square root gives $k = \pm \sqrt{m^2 + n^2}$, which is the correct way to apply the square root. The important part is to notice that $\sqrt{m^2 + n^2}$ is not the same as $\sqrt{m^2} + \sqrt{n^2}$

Comment: What we need here is [a cure for the “law of universal linearity”](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/630339/856).

Comment: To me it doesn't make much sense to ask "why" X doesn't equal Y when there's no reason to suggest they're equal in the first place.

Comment: The law does hold if the domain of the variables is restricted to the integers modulo 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the question in a broader context you may understand it better.

Suppose $f$ is some function you can apply to numbers. It might be squaring, or square-rooting, or inverting, or raising to some other power, or taking logarithms or $\sin$ or $\cos$ or just adding 15. In none of these cases is $f(x+y)$ the same as $f(x) + f(y)$ (you should check). In general, you would not expect that coincidence.

The special case in which it is true is the function "multiply by a fixed quantity". That's the distributive law:

$$
c \times (x + y ) = c \times x + c \times y .
$$

Many of the most common errors students make in algebra or precalculus come from thinking that those other functions behave this way too.

Edit: Just in case you missed @Rahul 's comment: What we need here is a cure for the “law of universal linearity”: [Pedagogy: How to cure students of the "law of universal linearity"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity)

Comment: A small point: there exist non-linear functions that satisfy $$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$$ for all $x,y$.

[This was a bit unintuitive for me](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032565/functions-that-satisfy-fxy-fxfy-and-f1-e). Edit: It is possible to prove that these functions exist, but probably not possible to write one down explicitly ... very strange!

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee True, but I won't edit "The special case" to "A special case" since the question is tagged algebra-precalculus.

Answer (score 1):

"Why is this true?"
(that $f(x+y) \ne f(x)+f(y)$).

Because
the functions that satisfy
$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
and are not badly behaved
(continuous will work)
are all *linear*,
so that
$f(x) = cx$
for some real $c$.

So if you try
$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$,
you can not have
$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$.

There are (at least)
two ways to prove this.

First,
if 
$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$,
then
$\sqrt{x+y} = \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$,
then,
squaring,
we get
$x+y = x+y+2\sqrt{xy}$,
so that
$2\sqrt{xy} = 0$,
so that
$xy = 0$,
or at least one of $x$
and $y$ is zero.

Second,
if we use the result
that $f(x) = cx$
for some real $c$,
then
$\sqrt{x} = cx$.
Squaring and dividing by $x$,
we get
$1=c^2x$,
which can not hold
for any constant $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be shown by the triangle inequality. Another way to look at it is for $k^2 = m^2 + n^2$ and $k = m + n$ you have that $(m+n)^2 = m^2 + n^2$ which is only true when either m or n are 0. In other words, the inequality only holds if you assume $m, n$ are nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $k,m,n$ as the sides of a triangle. Then:

- $k^2 = m^2 + n^2$ means that the triangle is a *right* triangle.
- $k = m +n$ means that the triangle is a *degenerate* triangle.

Clearly, no right triangle can be degenerate!

(Unless one of the sides is zero, in which case, yes, $k^2 = m^2$ implies $k=m$.)

Comment: You can have degenerate right triangles if one side is zero, right?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Otherwise
$\sqrt n = n$ for all natural number $n$.

More generally 
$\sqrt q = q$ for all positive rational number $q$.

*Homework:*

Is it true that:
$\sqrt x  = x$ for all positive real number $x$?