# Why isn't $(2x+x^2)^{1/2}$ the same as $(2x)^{1/2}+x$?

Tags: arithmetic

I just don't get why this isn't true.

Comment: Why should they be the same?  To convince yourself that they are different, try particular values of $x$, like $x=1$.

Comment: For the same reason that $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5$ is not the same as $\sqrt{3^2}+\sqrt{4^2}=7$

Comment: Why don't you try to do the opposite? Solve the equation $\sqrt{2x+x^2} = \sqrt{2x} + x$ and determine for which values of $x$ does the equation hold... You will see that $x=0$ is the only solution!

Comment: @Ethan makes a good point. Another point to consider is that, in general, $$\left(x^2\right)^\frac12=|x|.$$

Answer (score 4):

let $y=(2x+x^2)^{0.5}$. And $z=(2x)^{0.5} +x$. Then $y^2=2x+x^2$ and $z^2 =((2x)^{0.5}+x)^{2}$. Then it should be clear that $z$ can not be equal to $y$ since the well defined operations do not match. Therefore, you can not define it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a power of something isn't a linear operation

Comment: +1, absolutely correct, but I am afraid will be totally lost on the OP...

Answer (score 3):

Why should it be true. other than wishful thinking? When you first learn algebra you remember the distributive law for "multiplication by a fixed constant $a$", namely
$$
a(x + y) = ax +ay .
$$
That is true because you can prove it, first for integers and then for any real numbers.

But, sadly,
$$
(x + y)^2  \ne x^2 + y ^2 \\
$$
$$
\sqrt{x + y}  \ne \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}
$$
$$
a^{x + y}  \ne a^{x} + a^{y}
$$
$$
\log(x + y)  \ne \log{x} + \log{y}
$$
$$
\sin(x + y)  \ne \sin{x} + \sin{y}
$$

See

- [Pedagogy: How to cure students of the "law of universal linearity"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity)
- [Why is the square root of a sum not equal to the square root of each its addends?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718013/why-is-the-square-root-of-a-sum-not-equal-to-the-square-root-of-each-its-addends/1718049#1718049)

Comment: law of universal linearity is a great phrase ... I'm stealing that.

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
\sqrt{2x + x^2} = \sqrt{x(2+x)} = \sqrt{x} \sqrt{2+x}
$$
but in general,
$$
\sqrt{a+b} \ne \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}.
$$
Suppose this "equality" indeed held, then squaring both sides yields
$$
a+b = a + b + 2\sqrt{ab} \iff \sqrt{ab} = 0
$$
So you can see either $a=0$ or $b=0$ are needed for your "equality" to hold...

Comment: I used to give this kind of argument, but what if the student mistakenly thinks $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$? Then your argument just shows $a+b=a+b$ and the student will think they are correct... (Of course, some assumptions are being made on the parts of $a$ and $b$, but when thinking like a student, I don't find it unwarranted).

Comment: Then they should be taught that $(a+b)^2=(a+b)(a+b)$ and how to expand that out.

Comment: @RhysHughes "Multiply that out" using the distributive law, not "factor that out".

Comment: I corrected it to "expand" before your comment. Factor is the inverse and I realised this just after I wrote the comment

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a picture convinces you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Square both, you see:

$$(\sqrt{2x+x^2})^2\equiv(\sqrt{2x}+x)^2$$

$$2x+x^2\equiv(\sqrt{2x}+x)(\sqrt{2x}+x)\equiv2x+x^2+2x\sqrt{2x}$$
$$\implies 0\equiv2x\sqrt 2x$$
which is clearly false.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Test the equation with $x=1$. You will see that your equations give different results. The square root is the inverse of the square operator. It is clear that $(a+b)^2\neq a^2 + b^2$ hence the inversion $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is in general not equal to $|a+b|$.

Answer (score 0):

This is (a version of) the "freshman's binomial". While it *is* true in characteristic $p$ that $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$, this is false in general.